# Regex match just one time

Tags: regex

I'm using this regex to mach some words without numbers and it works well

```
(?:searchfor|\G).+?(\b[^\d\s]+?\b)
```

The problem that it's searching the hole document and not only in the line that contains searchfor

So if I have 2 times searchfor it will take them twice

I want to stop it only on that 1st line so it will not search the other lines after
Any help please?

I'm using Regex with php

Thank you

Comment: put `{1}` after your statement?

Comment: Where exactly? didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

you can reference two function:

```
 preg_match
 preg_match_all
```

Comment: Hello, I'm obliged to use preg_match_all any help please?